# Gmail SMTP always shows from reception as my personal email address

Tags: php

I' am trying to send mail using Gmail SMTP. The code works fine. The problem is the from reception it always shows my personal email address I want to show no-reply@domain.com

What seems to be missing?

```
 <?php
        require_once "Mail.php";
        $from = "No-Reply<no-reply@domain.com>";
        $to = "Test Reception <reception@gmail.com>";
        $subject = "Hi!";
        $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
        $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "example@gmail.com";
        $password = "password";

        $headers = array (
            'From' => $from,
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject);
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
            array (
                'host' => $host,
                'port' => $port,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password)
        );
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume because GMail knows who you are (because you logged in) and doesn't allow you to spoof the sender.

Comment: This is exactly it, gmail, and many other services now, don't let you spoof the address. You can set the name to anything you want but the from will always be reset. There is a way around it though, if you setup "send from another account" on gmail you can then change the address to one of the added accounts. A simpler way is to use a third party provider like http://sendgrid.com/ which has a free tier.